# jQuery onclick don't work with a href and img

Tags: jquery, html, cordova

I want to display divs when clicking on Link to the ID.

jQuery:

```
  $('#tab-bar a').on('click', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var nextPage = $(e.target.hash);
    page(nextPage);
    $("#pages .current").removeClass("current");
    nextPage.addClass("current");
    });
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="pages">
     <div id="mainpage" class="current">
      <ul id="tab-bar">
    <li>
    <a href="#mimik"><img src="img/mimik.jpg"  alt="mimik"></img></a><br>
    </li>
      </ul>
     </div>

  <div id="mimik">
   <h2 style="color:red">Mimik</h2>
  </div>
```

When i use text instead of the image in the  it works as i wish. The h2 is displayed.
With the image in as "link" it displays a blank page.
How can i solve this problem?

best regards
Simon

Comment: `<img src="img/mimik.jpg"  alt="mimik"></img>` should be `<img src="img/mimik.jpg"  alt="mimik" />`

Comment: Can you give us a fiddle? or at least the not working code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because when you have image inside anchor the event target is an `img` element when you click on it and it doesn't have any `hash` property. Try this where I am using `closest` method to find the closest `a` element from the target element.

```
$('#tab-bar a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var nextPage = $($(e.target).closest('a')[0].hash);
    page(nextPage);
    $("#pages .current").removeClass("current");
    nextPage.addClass("current");
});
```

Alternatively you can use `this.hash` where `this` will point to the element on which event is attached.

```
$('#tab-bar a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var nextPage = $(this.hash);
    page(nextPage);
    $("#pages .current").removeClass("current");
    nextPage.addClass("current");
});
```

Comment: Would `this.hash` perhaps work as well? The event handler is bound to the `a` elements.

Comment: Yup, that will be simplest solution :P